# Error with php_http: the program can't start because php_propro.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: php, windows, dll, php-extension, pecl

I'm trying to install php_http on Windows.

My Config is:

```
PHP Version => 5.3.13                                           
Build Date => May 14 2012 02:46:11  
Compiler => MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008) 
Architecture => x64                 
Thread Safety => enabled
```

So I finaly found a version of the php_http.dll that is compiled with MSVC9, with x64 architecture and with thread safety enabled. Howewer, now when I try to run a php script I get: The program can't start because php_propro.dll is missing from your computer. I know php_http depends on php_propro, but I can't find such a dll on the internet at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to build my own local server under Windows. I got the same issue.
To fix that, I installed the [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679). I never see again this error.

So, for me, the solution in your case should be **almost** the same.
You have mention the MSVC9 with a x64 architecture. So, you need to install the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336).

---

Source : The [PHP website](http://windows.php.net/download/).
Look at the block of information (on the left) which have the (main) title **Which version do I choose ?**
Inside you'll find note about the **VC9 and VC11**.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a version of that dll on http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=26283#26283

Answer (score 0):

php_prppro.dll can be downloaded from windows.php.net website here: http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/propro/1.0.0/